# Query Multiple Tables For Specific Date Range Simultaneously

Tags: mysql, union

I have three identical tables:

- `gradbusdb.user`
- `gradedudb.user`
- `gradtheologydb.user`

In each table, I have `email` and `submited_date` in YYYY-MM-DD format. My end goal is to query all three tables at the same time but when I do a `UNION` between the 3 tables for the `email` and `submited_date` columns it ignores my `WHERE` condition and displays all results.

My current query is as follows:

```
SELECT email, submited_date FROM gradbusdb.user 
UNION
SELECT email, submited_date FROM gradedudb.user
UNION
SELECT email, submited_date FROM gradtheologydb.user
WHERE submited_date BETWEEN '2016-02-01' AND '2016-02-29'
ORDER BY submited_date ASC
```

I am not sure what I have done wrong here but I need my query to display ONLY the results that are within the date range.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use WHERE for each query into union

```
SELECT email, submited_date FROM gradbusdb.user 
WHERE submited_date BETWEEN '2016-02-01' AND '2016-02-29'
UNION
SELECT email, submited_date FROM gradedudb.user
WHERE submited_date BETWEEN '2016-02-01' AND '2016-02-29'
UNION
SELECT email, submited_date FROM gradtheologydb.user
WHERE submited_date BETWEEN '2016-02-01' AND '2016-02-29'

ORDER BY submited_date ASC
```

Comment: Thank you! I knew it was something simple, I just couldn't think of how to set it up properly.

Comment: Out of curiosity, how did you style my question with the appropriate tags? I have been trying to solve this but havent seemed to figure out the WYSIWYG editor used above?

Comment: There are tags input while you editing/answering questions (but I haven't add any question yet:) only edited)